# Insert knitr (1.9) Chunks From Separate File Into Lyx (2.12) Document

Tags: lyx, knitr

I have a LyX document (report class) called mwe.lyx and I would like to execute the following Rmd chunk called "mwe.Rmd".

> `{r, eval = FALSE, echo = TRUE, cache = FALSE}
>   2+2`

Of course, I can simply use the chunk environment in LyX, but I would strongly prefer a solution in which I can keep my Rmd files external to my LyX file without copy-pasting from Rmd to LyX.

Alternately, if I could have the functionality of child document in LyX with the graphical display given by knitr, that would also be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yihui Xie, author of knitr, writes in his new book "Dynamic Documents with R and knitr" that:

> Note that currently Rnw is the only possible format to use in LYX. It
>   seems we are mixing R code with LYX, but LYX is really only a wrapper
>   so we are actually embedding R code in Rnw documents.

Unfortunately, it seems that I will have to either reformat all my materials from .Rmd's to .Rnw's, reformat them to regular R files and bring them using read_chunk or source, or copy-paste all of my R code into LyX.